# streamWrite with append option and window function

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to writeStream using the append option, but I get an error.

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, column, count, when

spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("get_sensor_data")\
        .getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

Sensor = lines.select(lines.value.alias('Sensor'),
        lines.timestamp)

windowedCounts = Sensor.withWatermark('timestamp', '10 seconds').groupBy(
        window(Sensor.timestamp, windowDuration, slideDuration)).\
        agg(count(when(col('Sensor')=="LR1 On",True)).alias('LR1'),\
        count(when(col('Sensor')=="LR2 On",True)).alias('LR2'),\
        count(when(col('Sensor')=="LD On",True)).alias('LD')).\
        orderBy('window')

query = windowedCounts\
        .writeStream\
        .outputMode('append')\
        .format("console")\
        .start()
```

Error:

```
Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark
```

The reason for using the append option is to save as a CSV file later.
I think this problem is caused by the window function, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Hi Shin, welcome to SO. Could you please ask an actual question so we can help you come to an answer?

Comment: Thanks for your command. I apologize for my unclear question. I am not good at writing English yet. But reading is good. I would really appreciate it if you could help me with my problem. thanks